# Cannot create dynamic JSX tags from string

Tags: string, reactjs, dynamic, tags

I'm trying to call my react components with JSX using a string instead of writing the JSX tag directly.

I'm storing tag names in a separate XML file that contains the tag name and other details. 'Tabs' is passed as 'ElementTagString'
    
    `<element>
       <componentTag>Tabs</componentTag>
    </element>`

````
addElement = (ElementTagString) => { // ElementTagString = 'Tabs'
 const ElementTag = <ElementTagString/>
 return <ElementTag/> // would be equivilent to writing <Tabs/> directly, calling my component.
}

// tabs component defined elsewhere
export function Tabs(props) {
    return (
        ...
    );
}



```I'm getting the following errpr:
<Tabs /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.```
````

I tried the following solutions with no result:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33471928/9983270

https://reactkungfu.com/2016/11/dynamic-jsx-tags/

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create react components with JSX using a string. What you can do is store your components in an object like this :

```
import Tabs from './tabs';
import PhotoStory from './photo';
import VideoStory from './video';

const components = {
  Tabs: Tabs
  Photo: PhotoStory,
  Video: VideoStory
};
```

Then in your function :

```
addElement = (ElementTagString) => {
 const ComponentName = components[ElementTagString];
 return <ComponentName  />;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it is the soltuion, look here also : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172587/1836175

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, I've upvoted, thank you. However, when I try to compile with webpack it says "Unexpected token ---> return <components[ElementTagString] />", so I had to assign the value to an uppercase variable "const ComponentName = components[ElementTagString];" and then "return <ComponentName />;" Only after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at run-time, as JSX `<whatever>` tags are converted into `React.createElement` function call.

See my solution with full description of what happens behind the scene here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55167475/1786034